# C++ How to add two arrays of unequal sizes using the for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays

So the aim is to take two arrays as shown below

```
int x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int k[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

and add each element of k to each element of x in a loop as shown

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
+1 +2 +3 +4 +1 +2 +3 +4 +1  +2
```

This should give us a final array [2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 12].

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the indexes of the larger array, using the modulus (`%`) operator to wrap-around the indexes when accessing the smaller array.

```
int x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int k[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int res[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    res[i] = x[i] + k[i % 4];
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/dt2bGw)

Answer (score 1):

With `%` you can have the wrap-around behavior and with `std::size`(from C++17 onwards) the size of the array.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   int x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
   int k[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   for(int i = 0; i < std::size(x); ++i)
   {
       x[i] = x[i] + k[i%std::size(k)];
   }

    //lets confirm if x has the right elmennts 
    for(const int& element: x)
        {
            std::cout<< element<<std::endl;
        }
}
```

Note that here i have not used a separate array to store the resulting array. Instead the elements are added into the original array `x`. Storing the result in a new array is **trivial**.